# How to extract common react hooks to a package inside a monorepo?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, babeljs, monorepo

I am trying to extract some common hooks that will be used in multiple projects inside multiple `nextjs` apps. But I keep encountering the following error

```
error - ../../packages/web-hooks/useClientDimensions.tsx
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (3:7)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file.
```

I narrowed down the problem to the `webpack` not being able to process the package as `typescript`.

Folder structure

```
|
|__ apps
|  |__react-native-app
|  |__next-app
|__ backend
|  |__express-app
|__ packages
   |__ web-hooks
   |__ native-hooks
```

I haven't made any changes to the `nextjs` `package.json` and `tsconfig.json` files.

packages/web-hooks/package.json

```
{
    "name": "web-hooks",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "index.ts",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {},
    "devDependencies": {
        "typescript": "4.7.4"
    },
    "peerDependencies": {
        "react": "^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC"
}
```

packages/web-hooks/tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "declaration": true,
        "declarationMap": true,
        "target": "ES5",
        "jsx": "react",
        "module": "CommonJS"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I figured out the problem. It is a [bug](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/20374) in the NextJS. Basically, it will not allow you to use a ts file outside its directory. This was the intended behavior, so not exactly a bug, more like a decided behavior. You can however modify this behavior by setting an experimental flag `externalDir` to `true` in `next.config.json`.

```
const nextConfig = {
    reactStrictMode: true,
    swcMinify: true,
    experimental: {
        externalDir: true, //set the flag to true
    },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

I would recommend reading the entire bug report before opting in for this though as this is an experimental feature and has some 'gotchas'.